# How does one change the value of a variable within an if statement

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, scope

```
<body>
<pre>

<form>
<strong> Height:</strong>      <input id ="Height"><br/>
<strong> Base: </strong>       <input id ="Base"><br/>
<strong> Hypotenus: </strong>  <input id ="Hypotenus"><br/>
</form>

<button type ="Button" onclick="Evaluate()">Find Area</button>
<p id ="Answer"> Answer will appear here </p>
<script>
function Evaluate() {
    var H = document.getElementById("Height").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("Base").value;
    var Hy = document.getElementById("Hypotenus").value;

    if (B == NaN || null) {
        var Area = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Hy, 2) - Math.pow(H, 2));
    }
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = Area;
}
</script>
</body>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and I've been trying to make a code that finds the formula of a triangle. My problem is after the if statement I would like to change the value of "Area" but I keep getting `undefined` everytime I run the code. How do I change the value of a variable within an if statement?

Comment: First, you start by using a proper condition, as in `if ( B == NaN || B == null )`, then you realize that an elements value will *never* be NaN nor null, because it's always a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how logical expressions work in JavaScript and will not give you the result you expect:

```
if (B == NaN || null) {
```

You have to make two separate comparisons instead and combine them with `||`:

```
if (B === NaN || B === null) {
```

---

Apart from that, an empty input will not have a `NaN` or `null` value, but simply an empty string. You may be looking for this check:

```
if (B.length === 0) {
```

Or, even shorter:

```
if (!B) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if()` statement will always be falsey, so actually your `Area` variable is never being defined. Update the statement as follows:

```
if( isNaN(B) || null == B ) 
{
    var Area = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Hy, 2) - Math.pow(H, 2));
}
```

You may also wish to add an `else` block into the above, otherwise `document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = Area;` may append `undefined`.

Finally, you will also need to update the variable definitions, since using `.value` will always return a string; you can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`:

```
var H  = parseFloat( document.getElementById("Height"),
    B  = parseFloat( document.getElementById("Base").value ),
    Hy = parseFloat( document.getElementById("Hypotenus").value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what others said, instead of:

```
var Area = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Hy, 2) - Math.pow(H, 2));
```

should be:

```
var B = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Hy, 2) - Math.pow(H, 2));
var area = B*H/2;
```

Comment: ahh, i see. Thanks for info